# HashMap keySet changes not reflected in map

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to iterate on `HashMap` and rewrite some of the elements to the other map, but I have following problem:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Map<SubClass, String> map = new HashMap<SubClass,String>();
    Map<SubClass, String> anotherMap = new HashMap<SubClass,String>();
    map.put(new SubClass(), "10");

    for(SubClass i : map.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(i); // initial (because toString is implemented)
        System.out.println(map.get(i)); // 10
        // here it's ok...

        i.name="another";

        System.out.println(i); // another
        System.out.println(map.get(i)); // null!
        // but here it occurs that  map.get(i) returns null!

        anotherMap.put(i, map.get(i));
    }
    for(SubClass i : anotherMap.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(i); // another
        System.out.println(map.get(i)); // null!
    }
}
// SubClass has String name; and hashCode and equals implemented
```

According to javadoc:

> `java.util.Map.keySet()`
>
> Returns a Set view of the keys contained in this map. The set is backed by the map, so changes to the 
>        map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa. If the map is modified while an iteration over the set is in 
>        progress (except through the iterator's own remove operation), the results of the iteration are 
>        undefined. The set supports element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, 
>        via the Iterator.remove, Set.remove, removeAll, retainAll, and clear operations. It does not support the 
>        add or addAll operations.

It says "changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa". So why does it behave this way and most important: how can I overcome it to make both maps contain only modified key and non-null value?

UPDATE:
My friend did this test on java 1.5.0.19 (I have 1.7.0_03, and the same occurs on 1.5.0_21) and got correct output:

```
initial
10
another
10
```

UPDATE2:
Oh, he didn't implement hashCode/equals, so first update is irrelevant

Comment: You are changing the key... this will never work because your second call to map.get(i) is based on a different key than the first one

Comment: so what does mean this part of javadoc: "changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa"?

Comment: Changes in the set is not the same as changes in an element of the set

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're modifying the *key*, not the *map*. There is no way for `Map<K,V>` to detect that you have changed the object within it. To make the map "see" the change you will need to call `remove(originalKey)`, change the key, then call `put(modifiedKey,object)`.

Modifying the map would be a call to `clear`, `put`, `putAll`, or `remove`.

Comment: Take a look at my update, please. Why does it work for my friend, then?

Comment: It might work for your friend for this particular operation, but if `name` is part of the key object's `equals` or `hashCode` implementation, the map's behavior is _undefined_.  Generally, what this means in practice is that the map will behave unpredictably: entries that appear in the `entrySet` will not appear with `map.get(key)`; you can't remove entries corrupted in this way.  The map is _corrupted._

Comment: @AdamPierzchała I can't say without seeing your friends code.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm accepting your answer as it was the first correct one.

Answer (score 4):

Per the [java.util.Map javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Map.html):

> Note: great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map keys. The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is a key in the map.

In other words, maps aren't required to work correctly if you change the key objects in a way that affects how the keys will be indexed within the map.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `i.name = "another"` is changing the hashcode of the `SubClass  i` object, that's why you get back a `null` value.  The code will work if the `hashcode` function of `Subclass` does not use `name`.

And so when you call `anotherMap.put(i, map.get(i));` you are really calling `anotherMap.put(i, null);`

The purpose of the `HashMap` is to perform lookups in O(1) time.  That's why it takes the hashcode from `SubClass  i` and does not update it.  Your suggestion would require a lazy `HashMap`, but that would take O(n) time and defeat the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like:

```
for(SubClass i : map.keySet()) {
    Object old = map.get(i);

    i.name="another";

    anotherMap.put(i, old);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm answering myself, since my friend got better solution than anybody here before:

```
for (Map.Entry<SubClass, String> entry: map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey().name);
    System.out.println(entry.getValue());

    entry.getKey().name = "another";

    System.out.println(entry.getKey().name);
    System.out.println(entry.getValue());
}
```

this will work :)

Comment: I doubt this will work.  If `SubClass.equals()` or `hashCode` depends on `name`, then all this will do is corrupt the map and make its behavior essentially unpredictable.  You should _never_ modify key objects in a map, especially not in ways that affect their `equals()` or `hashCode()`.

Comment: Have you checked it? I checked and it works (for this simple example), why/when would it not work?

Comment: ok, I've read @Kenster's answer - haven't noticed this before in javadocs. I'll change the implementation.